# What are the limits of a turret's attack range?

Tags: league-of-legends

When you are standing under an enemy turret, but are not its target (say you are with a creep wave), damaging an enemy will make the turret target you. Does this have a range?

For example, if you are a champion like Teemo or Caitlyn that can place shrooms/traps that damage enemies, and an enemy walks into a trap in a different lane, will this cause the turret to attack you?

Is this possibly any different for more active long distance attacks (like Ashe or Ezreal's ulti)?

Comment: I would say probably not, but i'm not really sure about it. This is going to need some testing.

Comment: I dont feel like looking up the source, so I wont post as answer, but I can say with definity (I've played LoL a long time) that turret's only worry about what happens within the radius of their range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both comments are right. The turret only attacks you if the enemy champion you damage is in range of the turret.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret#Attack_Prioritization

Comment: You can see that as a help request. A champion can only ask for help within range.